# Constant decreasing memory allocation productivity. Code example

Tags: c++, memory, std

Could you please help to find out what is the reason of constant decreasing of the code performance below.
If you run the code, you will see that it prints out a number of iterations per every second. After 10-15 seconds the number of iterations per second is x2 smaller than in the beginning.
At first the problem occured in QT, but I reworked the code to test it with std, and the problem reproduces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <chrono>


using namespace std;

int64_t GetUsecTime()
{
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();
}

namespace IType {
    enum T {
        oI = 0,
        oI_2 = 1,
    };
}

class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass(IType::T t)
        : m_type(t)
    {}

    virtual ~BaseClass() {}

    IType::T type()
    {
        return m_type;
    }

private:
    IType::T m_type;
};

class InheritedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<InheritedClass> CreateShared(const string& some)
    {
        //return shared_ptr<InheritedClass>(new InheritedClass(some));
        return make_shared<InheritedClass>(some);
    }

    static shared_ptr<InheritedClass> CreateShared()
    {
        //return shared_ptr<InheritedClass>(new InheritedClass(some));
        return make_shared<InheritedClass>();
    }

    InheritedClass(const string& some)
        : BaseClass(IType::oI)
        , someFiled(some)
    {}

    InheritedClass()
        : BaseClass(IType::oI)
        , someFiled("")
    {}

    void setField(const string& value)
    {
        someFiled = value;
    }
private:
    string someFiled;
};


class InheritedClass_2 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<InheritedClass_2> CreateShared()
    {
        //return shared_ptr<InheritedClass_2>(new InheritedClass_2());
        return make_shared<InheritedClass_2>();
    }

    InheritedClass_2()
        : BaseClass(IType::oI_2)
    {}

    void setField(int value)
    {
        someFiled = value;
    }
private:
    int someFiled;
};

class someclass
{
public:
    someclass()
    {
        int64_t dataSize(0);
        int64_t oldDataSize(0);
        int64_t time0(GetUsecTime());
        int64_t time(time0);

        for (int i = 0; i<8000000; i++)
        {
            // TEST CONSTRUCTORS
            //auto instance=InheritedClass::CreateShared(); // No Problem...
            auto instance = InheritedClass::CreateShared(""); // PROBLEM!! With this line, speed is constantly decreasing

                                                              //TEST CODE:
                                                              //instance->setField("just something"); // PROBLEM!! With this line, speed is constantly decreasing

            V.push_back(instance);

            auto instance_2 = InheritedClass_2::CreateShared();
            instance_2->setField(i);
            V.push_back(instance_2);

            dataSize = i;

            if (GetUsecTime() - time > 1000000)
            {
                time = GetUsecTime();

                cout << "Processed: " << dataSize - oldDataSize << endl;

                oldDataSize = dataSize;
            }
        }

        cout << V.size() << " in " << (GetUsecTime() - time0) / 1000.0 << " ms" << endl;
    }
private:
    vector<shared_ptr<BaseClass> > V;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    someclass s;

    return 0;
}
```

2. 

the code ran in QT and Visual studio.
The printout from QT program below (decreasing from 220000 to 67000:

```
Processed: 31681
Processed: 196038
Processed: 234112
Processed: 229468
Processed: 216378
Processed: 227070
Processed: 198330
Processed: 211321
Processed: 197137
Processed: 151333
Processed: 167995
Processed: 168307
Processed: 163719
Processed: 153696
Processed: 110894
Processed: 143917
Processed: 137006
Processed: 129974
Processed: 127678
Processed: 124093
Processed: 124029
Processed: 123018
Processed: 118595
Processed: 116676
Processed: 115023
Processed: 73030
Processed: 111768
Processed: 110222
Processed: 103588
Processed: 106266
Processed: 105271
Processed: 105031
Processed: 102042
Processed: 100258
Processed: 99404
Processed: 98955
Processed: 97007
Processed: 95901
Processed: 93696
Processed: 91405
Processed: 91061
Processed: 90175
Processed: 87727
Processed: 87448
Processed: 85510
Processed: 84238
Processed: 41837
Processed: 76040
Processed: 75694
Processed: 82918
Processed: 81515
Processed: 80957
Processed: 79657
Processed: 80840
Processed: 79110
Processed: 78720
Processed: 76078
Processed: 76067
Processed: 75412
Processed: 75546
Processed: 74052
Processed: 73386
Processed: 69608
Processed: 66880
Processed: 68731
Processed: 70560
Processed: 68979
Processed: 69985
Processed: 70516
Processed: 68464
Processed: 67379
Processed: 67980
Processed: 67746
Processed: 67332
16000000 in 74537 ms
```

The printout from VisualSutio program below (initial values smaller, less stable, but not decreasing):

```
Processed: 81138
Processed: 78107
Processed: 81158
Processed: 101733
Processed: 69418
Processed: 99900
Processed: 54649
Processed: 94161
Processed: 95660
Processed: 31477
Processed: 97066
Processed: 97588
Processed: 99001
Processed: 99554
Processed: 492
Processed: 99197
Processed: 100049
Processed: 99765
Processed: 100066
Processed: 97667
Processed: 93807
Processed: 100146
Processed: 99378
Processed: 99824
Processed: 98228
Processed: 97943
Processed: 99552
Processed: 100299
Processed: 99753
Processed: 90703
Processed: 98276
Processed: 99480
Processed: 99569
Processed: 99528
Processed: 99058
Processed: 98939
Processed: 97637
Processed: 99334
Processed: 99713
Processed: 99540
Processed: 99212
Processed: 99339
Processed: 98781
Processed: 40334
Processed: 98810
Processed: 99134
Processed: 99953
Processed: 99884
Processed: 99891
Processed: 100036
Processed: 100037
Processed: 98182
Processed: 98393
Processed: 99091
Processed: 98359
Processed: 99515
Processed: 100710
Processed: 99065
Processed: 100507
Processed: 99915
Processed: 96591
Processed: 97256
Processed: 100400
Processed: 99551
Processed: 7829
Processed: 100520
Processed: 99480
Processed: 100201
Processed: 99145
Processed: 100898
Processed: 100403
Processed: 99873
Processed: 99761
Processed: 99590
Processed: 99795
Processed: 100142
Processed: 99396
Processed: 99607
Processed: 98091
Processed: 97379
Processed: 98045
Processed: 98448
Processed: 97853
Processed: 98633
Processed: 96140
16000000 in 96518.3 ms
```

Comment: If you would tag a language (C++ I guess) you might attract more users of the helpful and topic-knowing kind.

Comment: You're making quite a few unnecesary copies with `make_shared` . `make_shared<InheritedClass>(some)` and `make_shared<InheritedClass_2>()` are enough. (`make_shared` does not take an object and make it shared, it makes a shared object.)

Comment: I played with make_shared, and just shared_ptr(), no influence on the mentioned problem itself. Nevertheless, thanks for tip.

Comment: Here's my guess: `someField` will always be default constructed. I think that the compiler can remove `someFiled("")` initialization in the second constructor. But likely it has problems removing the empty string from `::CreateShared("")` line. And empty strings are not free, no no. While implementation dependent, it is likely that non-zero memory (capacity) is allocated for it under the hood. And so `::CreateShared("")` is twice as heavy as `::CreateShared()`.

Comment: It also seems to be compiler dependent, see this: https://godbolt.org/z/GPod3z Clang generates really bad code for check2. But Gcc produces the same code for both.

Comment: I understand all your answers, but all of them can only explain the difference of the behavior on different compilers. I would like to ask you to run the code for one minute, and you will see that the output values will always be decreasing by some % every time. This is so far not clear.

Comment: I ran the code in QT and VisualStudio. Tricky enough, the program in VS is slower (output printouts are smaller), but they do not decrease! On QT, strangely enough, the values are more stable, they start from bigger value, but continuosly decreasing. It looks like dependency from the memory already allocated, and 2nd, has something to do with the internal String field in the instance1. The code is quite simple, but my knowledge is not enough to explain all those tricky things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the program during the test was running in QT debugger.
2. When made a release, and run it from Windows just as EXE, it worked 20 times faster! and without those slowing down.

So, solution:

- Do not trust when run your code in QT debugger - it is several times slower than the real app!
- Do not measure time / do not estimate performance from QT debugger.

New printout from realeas exe:

```
Processed: 1923592
Processed: 2062627
Processed: 1993109
Processed: 2541079
Processed: 1666522
Processed: 2562799
Processed: 1186022
Processed: 2578212
Processed: 2590275
40000000 in 9599 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happens due to `std::vector` grows with power of two every time when there is no room for new items. When this occurs it copies the current content to new allocated space. When items number becomes large it makes the delay noticeable.

Also to find out the line where the CPU wasted mostly it's quite necessary to use profiler. Another way tries like commenting and uncommenting part of code won't give the precise understanding where the issue is and how to optimize.

Comment: I tried list and deque, no change. But I updated the topic message, and Visual Studio gives other result (no continuously decreasing behaviour), with the same code. So, vector, probably, is not the reson, if it is not a reason for VisualStudio compiler? By the way, vector is NOT a reason, because you can only comment out the lines with // PROBLEM mark, and get everything working fine, without slowing down.

Comment: May be. To find out exactly consider using profiler. This will save your time.

Comment: @Dmitry Gorelov Commenting and uncommenting lines of code can have side effects and induce issues. I don't insist that this has place in your case, but the only way to find out and resolve this is to profile code.

Comment: Thank you 4xy, I am looking for a profiler. Nevertheless, I just hope that the code is not so much complicated, and someone experienced in similar problems could give an answer. So lets the question keep unresolved for a couple of days.